# SQL Delete Statement Didnt Delete

Tags: sql, t-sql

Just want to get some views/possible leads on an issue I have.

I have a stored procedure that updates/deletes a record from a table in my database, the table it deletes from is a live table, that temporary holds the data, and also updates records on a archive table. (for reporting etc..) it works normally and havent had an issues.

However recently I had worked on a windows service to monitor our system (running 24/7), which uses a HTTP call to initiate a program, and once this program has finished it then runs the mention stored procedure to delete out redundant data. Basically the service just runs the program quickly to make sure its functioning correctly.

I have noticed recently that the data isnt always being deleted. Looking through logs I see no errors being reported. And Even see the record in the database has been updated correctly. But just doesnt get deleted.

This unfortunately has a knock on effect with the monitoring service, as this continously runs, and sends out alerts because the data cant be duplicated in the live table, hence why it needs to delete out the data.

Currently I have in place a procedure to clear out any old data. (3 hours).

Result has the value - Rejected.

Below is the stored procedure:

```
    DECLARE @PostponeUntil DATETIME;
DECLARE @Attempts INT;
DECLARE @InitialTarget VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @MaxAttempts INT;
DECLARE @APIDate DATETIME;

--UPDATE tCallbacks SET Result = @Result WHERE CallbackID = @CallbackID AND UPPER(Result) = 'PENDING';

UPDATE tCallbacks SET Result = @Result WHERE ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM tCallbacks WHERE CallbackID = @CallbackID ORDER BY ID DESC)

SELECT @InitialTarget = C.InitialTarget, @Attempts = LCB.Attempts, @MaxAttempts = C.CallAttempts
FROM tConfigurations C WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN tLiveCallbacks LCB ON LCB.ID = @CallbackID
WHERE C.ID = LCB.ConfigurationID;

IF ((UPPER(@Result) <> 'SUCCESSFUL') AND (UPPER(@Result) <> 'MAXATTEMPTS') AND (UPPER(@Result) <> 'DESTBAR') AND (UPPER(@Result) <> 'REJECTED')) BEGIN
    --INSERT A NEW RECORD FOR RTNR/BUSY/UNSUCCESSFUL/REJECT
    --Create Callback Archive Record

    SELECT @APIDate = CallbackRequestDate FROM tCallbacks WHERE Attempts = 0 AND CallbackID = @CallbackID;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    INSERT INTO tCallbacks (CallbackID, ConfigurationID, InitialTarget, Agent, AgentPresentedCLI, Callee, CalleePresentedCLI, CallbackRequestDate, Attempts, Result, CBRType, ExternalID, ASR, SessionID)
        SELECT ID, ConfigurationID, @InitialTarget, Agent, AgentPresentedCLI, Callee, CalleePresentedCLI, @APIDate, @Attempts + 1, 'PENDING', CBRType, ExternalID, ASR, SessionID
        FROM tLiveCallbacks
        WHERE ID = @CallbackID;

    UPDATE LCB 
    SET PostponeUntil = DATEADD(second, C.CallRetryPeriod, GETDATE()),
        Pending = 0,
        Attempts = @Attempts + 1
    FROM tLiveCallbacks LCB
    LEFT JOIN tConfigurations C ON C.ID = LCB.ConfigurationID
    WHERE LCB.ID = @CallbackID;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE BEGIN
    -- Update the Callbacks archive, when Successful or Max Attempts or DestBar.
    IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM tLiveCallbacks WHERE ID = @CallbackID) BEGIN

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        UPDATE  tCallbacks 
        SET Attempts = @Attempts 
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP (1) ID 
                             FROM tCallbacks 
                             WHERE CallbackID = @CallbackID 
                             ORDER BY Attempts DESC);

        -- The live callback should no longer be active now. As its either been answered or reach the max attempts.
        DELETE FROM tLiveCallbacks WHERE ID = @CallbackID;
        COMMIT
    END
END
```

Comment: How and where is `@Result` set? Because it looks like you have a race condition between when you get `@Result` and when you do the `IF` statement. You should also consider wrapping the entire stored procedure in a transaction rather than just the branches of the `IF` statement.

Comment: Another hint as to where the problem *might* be coming from, is how you seem to check against having multiple records in `tCallbacks` for a given `CallbackID`, is this a possibility in your data?

Comment: @Result is passed over as a parameter. For this situation where I noticed it, is when Result is set to Rejected. CallbackID can appear multiple times in tCallbacks, as it has to count for each attempt with a callbackID. I have also thought of wrapping it in a try catch block, would this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your transaction processing. What is happening is that one statement is failing but since you don't have a try-catch block all changes are not getting rolled back only the statement that failed.

You should never have a begin tran without a try catch block and a rollback on error. I personally also prefer in something like this to put the errors and associated data into a table variable (which will not rollback) and then insert then to an exception table after the rollback. This way the data retains integrity and you can look up what the problem was.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have redesigned the Stored Procedure to use a try catch block with a transaction, to be honest I have only recently discovered try catch blocks exist in SQL, when I originally developed this over 6 months ago, I didnt know, so going back over old code. Thats also a really good idea with the use of an exceptions table.

Comment: The exception table really will help when something that has been working fine for months stops working.